# Schema for Siebel header

Tags: xsd, jdeveloper, bpel, soapheader, siebel

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
          <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
          <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
```

The above lines are entered as XML fragment in a BPEL process in JDeveloper.
Question: How do I design a suitable schema to get Username and Password for Siebel header to call out Siebel services?

Comment: Follow up: I added a new .xsd file with one element: Sequence is Username, Password (each of string type). I assigned the corresponding strings using 'assign' operation in the BPEL process and replaced the existing header variable with a new variable (of the new element type) in the invoke operation. Build was successful. However, the invoke operation gave an error during testing.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of request to siebel web services with WSSOAP option turned on:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns:UsernameToken xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://siebel.com/webservices" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">User name goes here</ns:UsernameToken>
        <ns:PasswordText xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://siebel.com/webservices" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">Password goes here</ns:PasswordText>
        <ns:SessionType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://siebel.com/webservices" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">Session type goes here</ns:SessionType>
        <ns:SessionToken xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://siebel.com/webservices" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">Session token goes here</ns:SessionToken>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

without WSSOAP option you would have to either invoke that as anonymous user (configured on Siebel side) or put user name & password in URL.
Here you can find more information (Siebel Bookshelf): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/EAI2/EAI2_WebServices.html